# Разделение string на элементы массива через нужный символ

Tags: c++

Подскажите, а способа как использовать <vector> для разделения нужной мне строки на подстроки, которые будут заноситься в массив, нет?

Нужно из:

> "Привет; Как; Дела"

Получить:

```
str[0]="Привет";
str[1]="Как";
str[2]="Дела";
```

Как в PHP - explode, а C# - split

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c

Comment: все ответы считаю неуместными, особенно тот ответ, который помечен как лучший - там вообще нет смысла использовать вектор, так как string сам построен на векторах. Мне интересно, как устроен метод LoadFromFile у TStringList(delphi, c++builder)? Пробовал разными способами добиться такой скорости разделения на строки, как у метода LoadFromFile - не получается...Но там явно не посимвольный линейный перебор(при таком способе вообще в 100 раз медленнее получается)

Comment: данную задачу можно решить только посимвольным перебором. Другое дело, как это делать и как кешировать.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вроде это то, что вы хотели:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  vector<string> arr;
  string str ("Привет; Как; Дела");
  string delim("; ");
  size_t prev = 0;
  size_t next;
  size_t delta = delim.length();

  while( ( next = str.find( delim, prev ) ) != string::npos ){
    //Отладка-start
    string tmp = str.substr( prev, next-prev );
    cout << tmp << endl;
    //Отладка-end
    arr.push_back( str.substr( prev, next-prev ) );
    prev = next + delta;
  }
  //Отладка-start
  string tmp = str.substr( prev );
  cout << tmp << endl;
  //Отладка-end
  arr.push_back( str.substr( prev ) );

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Стандартного способа нет. Нужно 1) либо писать свою функцию, 2) либо подключать внешнюю библиотеку, 3) либо преобразовывать `std::string` в `c_str` и использовать `strtok`. Например,

```
char *s = new char[source.size() + 1];

strcpy(s, source.c_str());

char *p = strtok(s, ";");

while (p! = NULL) {
    cout << p << endl;
    p = strtok(NULL, ";");
}

delete[] s;
```

Answer (score 3):

Более "`C++`" способ следующий:

```
std::string sentence = "Hello how are you";
std::istringstream iss(sentence);
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          std::back_inserter<std::vector<std::string> >(tokens));
```

В этом случае, правда, нельзя указать свой собственный разделитель. В качестве более удобной альтернативы могу предложить [**`boost::string_algo`.**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/string_algo.html)

Answer (score 2):

вариант 1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string base_str = ", , ,, 1 Tin,  Tomn Tyt 65, gg, gh ,  ";   // пример строки
    string sep = ", ";   // строка или символ разделитель
    size_t sep_size = sep.size();
    string temp;
    while (true) {
        temp = base_str.substr(0, base_str.find(sep));
        if (temp.size() != 0)   // можно добавить доп. проверку для строк из пробелов
            cout << temp << endl;   // можно вставлять в массив вместо помещения в выходной поток
        if (temp.size() == base_str.size()) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            base_str = base_str.substr(temp.size() + sep_size);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

вариант 2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string base_str = ",, 11, 2222 , 33333,44, ";   // исходная строка
    string delim = ",";   // строка или символ разделитель
    size_t pos = 0;
    size_t base_str_size = base_str.size();
    size_t delim_size = delim.size();
    string temp;
    while (pos < base_str_size) {
        temp = temp.assign(base_str, pos, base_str.find(delim, pos) - pos);
        if (temp.size() > 0)  // проверка на пустую строку при необходимости
        cout << temp << endl;
        pos += temp.size() + delim_size;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

С++11 с regexp

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string value = "Hello, world";
    static const std::regex rdelim{", "};
    std::vector<std::string> words{
            std::sregex_token_iterator(value.begin(), value.end(), rdelim, -1),
            std::sregex_token_iterator()
       };
   for(const auto& str : words) {
       printf("%s \n", str.c_str());
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Такая реализация работает даже на msvc2010

```
std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems)
{
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim))
    {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim)
{
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string sText;
    std::getline(std::cin, sText);

    std::vector<std::string> sWords = split(sText, ';');

    return 0;
}
```